# Get console application from background processes

Tags: c#, .net, console

I develop C# console application which act like http server, and TeamCity deploy it to server using shared folder and run using PsExec, the problem is that application starts hidded in background and only place I can see it running is task manager.
Is there way to prevent it? Or maybe I can force application to show application window by some actions?

c:\tools\PsExec64.exe \192.168.1.1\ c:\portal\server.exe

Comment: What exactly have you tried doing? Help us help you by posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: MindSwipe i run console application on another windows server using PsExec and console app stats not visible, this should be enought to reproduce

Comment: If there is no code to be posted then you are on the wrong forum. I would recommend posting this question on [superuser](https://superuser.com)

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with C# console application. However, are you able to do this.

```
c:\tools\PsExec64.exe -s -i 0 \192.168.1.1\ c:\portal\server.exe
```

*-s* to run as system account and force it run on Session 0

*-i* to display interactive UI